# ReadFileEx not working on drive handle, claiming to be successful

Tags: c++, readfile

My code is designed to dump the first 512 bytes of raw data in a drive. CreateFileW works great in opening the handle, I've tested it with getting the drive geometry, so I know that it's not the problem. ReadFileEx then claims it's working, with GetLastError returning 0, but the buffer remains empty and no data is read. Here's my code:

```
#define UNICODE 1
#define _UNICODE 1

#include <windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define wszDrive L"\\\\.\\X:"
#define BUFFERSIZE 512
DWORD g_BytesTransferred = 0;

VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
    __in  DWORD dwErrorCode,
    __in  DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
    __in  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);

VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
    __in  DWORD dwErrorCode,
    __in  DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
    __in  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("Error code:\t%x\n"), dwErrorCode);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Number of bytes:\t%x\n"), dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    g_BytesTransferred = dwNumberOfBytesTransfered;
}

HANDLE GetDriveHandle(LPWSTR wszPath)
{
    HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    DWORD junk = 0;

    hDevice = CreateFileW(wszPath,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ |
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    return (hDevice);
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    ULONGLONG DiskSize = 0;
    char ReadBuffer[BUFFERSIZE] = { 0 };
    OVERLAPPED ol = { 0 };
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;

    HANDLE hDevice = GetDriveHandle(wszDrive);



    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Error Opening Drive");
    }
    else {
        printf("Drive Handle Opened. Starting Read.\n");
        ReadFileEx(hDevice, ReadBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, &ol, FileIOCompletionRoutine);
        if (dwBytesRead == 0) {
            printf("No Bytes Read. Error: %08x.\n", GetLastError());
        }
        ReadBuffer[dwBytesRead] = '\0';
        printf("%s", ReadBuffer);
    }

    CloseHandle(hDevice);

    while (true) {

    }

    return ((int)bResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the input handle, the documentation for ReadFileEx says:

> This parameter can be any handle opened with the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag by the CreateFile function, or a socket handle returned by the socket or accept function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468(v=vs.85).aspx

but you don't seem to be using that flag.

It also states:

> This handle also must have the GENERIC_READ access right. For more information on access rights, see File Security and Access Rights.